# Plink output on same line

Tags: python, plink

When I run the code :

```
os.system('plink -ssh -l root 192.168.107.3 -pw xxxxx -m "c:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\com.txt" > "c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\out.txt" 2>&1')
```

To connect to a remote system to run the commands and store its output in out.txt.

The com.txt (command text file) contains the commands: 
date &&
hwclock

Which gives the output in the out.txt in a single line such as:

---

Tue May 29 16:10:49 IST 2018 Tue May 29 16:10:40 2018  -0.522861 seconds

---

I need the output for each command in a new line such as:

---

Tue May 29 16:10:49 IST 2018

Tue May 29 16:10:40 2018  -0.522861 seconds

---

I tried adding

echo " "

between each command but it does not change the output text file.

Any help will be appreciated!

I am running python 2.7.12 on windows 10.

Comment: What happens if you write `date` and `hwclock` commands on separate lines?

Comment: Same issue. Output is still in single line.

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you run the command in a console CMD.exe? On my system I actually get 2 lines but separated with a single `\n` (Unix line separator) instead of a `\r\n` (Windows one).

Comment: When I run the command in the CMD.exe I get the desired output that is the result of the date and hwclock separated with a \n. How ever when I use redirection '>' to the out.txt file it redirects the output in a single line. 
Is this a windows issue?

Comment: Which  editor are you opening the file with? Notepad might not show new line without \r.

Comment: Yes exactly. I figured this our last night. 
When I opened the out.txt with wordpad it gave the output in separate lines. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the notepad doesn't show the '\n' and displays all the output in a single line. So when opened with wordpad the output was in separate lines as I wanted.

Hope it helps anyone facing this trivial issue.